# easy_install and pip giving errors when trying to install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip, easy-install

I am running Python 2.7.2 on my machine. I am trying to install numpy with easy_install and pip, but none of them are able to do so. So, when I try:

sudo easy_install-2.7 numpy

I get this error:

**"The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available."**

Moreover, when I try with pip:

sudo pip-2.7 install numpy

I get this error:

**RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program**

Is there any fix available for this?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error while installing the requirements for my django project. This worked for me.

Upgrade your setuptools version via **pip install --upgrade setuptools** and run the command for installing the packages again.

Comment: This works for me in Macos

Answer (score 2):

you need a compiler and development tools, along with header files for Python.

you didn't mention your OS.

on my system (Ubuntu), I can install python-dev and the toolchain dependencies with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

then I can pip install numpy.

Comment: kindly elaborate ... if I can keep my python version and just fix this issue?? is there a possibility?

Comment: install python-devel with your package manager or however you installed python.

Comment: I am running two versions (2.4 and 2.7) on my Red Hat 4.1.2-51 operating system. I installed python-devel using yum, that error is gone. However, I am still not able to 'easy_install-2.7 numpy' because now it gives this error: SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel. I also did yum install python-numpy and installed python-numpy. But, still I am not able install numpy on python distribution. Any ideas why?

Comment: sounds like you are missing python-2.7 headers